# Proof graph theory(length of a path)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In $G$ simple graph every vertex has the degree of $\delta$.

Proof, that in $G$ graph there is at most one $\delta$ long path.

I think that I should use in some way the Hamilton path, which says that in an undirected or directed graph that visits each vertex exactly once.
Or does the proof based on an induction?

Comment: Why do you believe that $G$ has an Hamiltonian path? There exist graphs having no Hamiltonian paths (for example, any star-shaped graph)

Comment: Just to be sure, does every vertex in the graph have degree $= \delta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously this is true for $\delta = 0$. So we consider $\delta \ge 1$.
Now, I construct inductively a path of legth $\delta$ in the following way:

1. start with a vertex $v_0$: this has degree $\delta \ge 1$, hence there exists some other vertex $v_1$ adjacent to $v_0$ and distinct from it.
2. repeat $\delta$ times the previous step, choosing every time a new vertex: this is allowed since every step $i \in \{ 1, \dots , \delta \}$ the vertex $v_{i-1}$ has at least $\delta > i-1$ adjacent vertices, so in particular there exist some $v_i$ distinct from the previous chosen which is adjacent to $v_{i-1}$.

Then the path $v_0, v_1, \dots , v_{\delta}$ has legth $\delta$.

Comment: You showed that there is a path of at least length $\delta$. However the OP asked to show there is at most one $\delta$ long path, which I think is false.